# Time Machine backup to a networked (no Airport or Time Capsule) drive

Tags: time-machine, backup, disk-utility, time-capsule

I followed [this tutorial to backup with Time Machine to a hard drive shared on the network](http://lifehacker.com/5691649/an-easier-way-to-set-up-time-machine-to-back-up-to-a-networked-windows-computer/all) (no Time Capsule, Airport).

However, when I go to Time Machine and click select backup disk, it simply opens Airport Utility and tries and fails in its search.

Does this method no longer work (Mavericks)?

Any alternate method to backup over network? I tried to create a system image from Disk Utility and save it to the networked drive, but met with a write permissions error -61.

I don't need Time Machine necessarily, just a system image before I do a factory restore on my Air. The SSD is nearly full, so I can't save the image locally. I don't have a big enough external drive either.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using OSX Server to do what you are attempting to do. Works pretty well over  wifi network. Not a free solution and probably overkill for what you're after.

Comment: Not an answer..